# jquery .append() working then disappearing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im working on a Wikiviewer for FreeCodeCamp and i've run into a strange issue.

I have just a basic example running right here (it aint pretty at all right now, just proof of concept):
http://codepen.io/msmith1114/pen/peBKxM?editors=1111

im appending here(in the JS code, there isn't very much):

```
$("#links").append('<li><a href="' + arrayLinks[0] + '">' + arrayName[0] + '</a></li>');
      $("#links").append('<li><a href="' + arrayLinks[1] + '">' + arrayName[1] + '</a></li>');
      $("#links").append('<li><a href="' + arrayLinks[2] + '">' + arrayName[2] + '</a></li>');
      })
```

So this really has 2 issues (and if you try it with console open you'll see)

1st Main issue: The list will show up (3 links) and then disappear...which makes no sense. jquery.append() should leave them there as far as Im aware, since im appending them to the  in my html section

2nd issue: It seems like sometimes getJSON will not return anything. I thought wrapping my statements in the .done() section would make sure not to do anything until the Wikipedia API has returned everything would work but sometimes you just don't get anything back. Is this a WikiAPI problem or something else? (BTW if it doesn't work, just keep typing in "cat" or something in the searchbox and hit search again, it'll eventually work until you run into problem 1 above).

Thanks. Im still learning JS/Jquery so im a bit puzzled why this won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue is because you've hooked to the click of the submit button. This doesn't stop the form submission, hence the page gets reloaded. Use the `submit` event of the `form` element instead and be sure to call `preventDefault()` on the provided event:

```
$(".form-inline").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // the rest of your code here...
});
```

As for the second issue, it could be a limiting issue. Without seeing an error it's going to be impossible to give you a definitive answer

Comment: This seems...like maybe im doing it the wrong way if that's needed? Is there maybe a better way for me to do this besides this? or is this how it would be done in most websites?

Comment: This is how it should be done. It's only changing one line of your code, and adding another

Comment: Here's an updated codepen using it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmJvvX?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't saying it was bad. I just didn't know if "there are better ways and my crappy layout just made us have to go with this way" that may or may not have a better way.