# jQuery appends dropdownlist, but appended item disappears on postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, dropdown, postback

I'm appending items to a dropdownlist using jQuery. Values are coming from a textbox on my page. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('#ddlProjectName').append( new Option($('#txtNewProjectName').val(), $('#txtNewProjectName').val()));
$('#ddlProjectName').val($('#txtNewProjectName').val());    //  select appended item
```

This seems to work fine; I can see the new item in my dropdown list, and it is the currently selected item. But when I select a different item in the dropdown list, my newly-appended item is no longer there. The c# in my code behind can't see it either.

The problem is that my dropdownlist is auto-posting back (to fire my code behind when my user makes a selection). This is what's clearing the appended item, but I don't know what to do about it.

I also tried:

```
$('#ddlProjectName').val($('#txtNewProjectName').val()).trigger('change');
```

No luck there. I've looked around this site and I really thought that  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260103/jquery-append-working-then-disappearing)  would get me somewhere, but I don't understand the answer.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described your dropdown is updated after selecting. So...
An optimal way would be to debug step-by-step and find where you dropdown updated and call your option adding code after that event.
If you have no control over it or you want to be *agnostic* (your code doesn't care what updates your dropdown) use `MutationObserver` to watch your dropdown for updates.

```js
// code you don't control

const fillSelect = () => 'name1 name2 name3'.split(' ').forEach(
  text => $('<option>', {value: text, text}).appendTo('select')
);

// this erases the options and fills them again thus destroying your extra options
$('select').on('change', () => $('select').empty() + fillSelect() + console.log('cleared by 3rd party'));

fillSelect();

// code you control

const appendSelect = () => {

  'append1 append2 append3'.split(' ').forEach(
    text => $('<option>', {value: text, text}).appendTo('select')
  );
  
  $('select').val('append3');
  console.log('appended extra options and set value');
};

appendSelect();

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => observer.disconnect() + appendSelect() + observe());

const observe = () => observer.observe($('select')[0], { childList: true });

observe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Hey Silent, let me chew on this. It will take me some time to work through, but I think I'm seeing the gist. Thanks so much for your detailed response.

Comment: @buckshot don't forget to accept my answer if it suits you ;-)